# Where is the source code of Ubuntu and how do I compile it?

Tags: software-installation, compiling, development, custom-distributions

I really want to make my own distro of linux but I do not know where to find the source code. Also I don't know how to compile it, is there any special way to compile Ubuntu and install everything.

Comment: There is a nice article about custom ubuntu distributions at [this link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DerivativeDistroHowto)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd has all you need to know. You do not need source code. You need to change the Ubuntu ISO you download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as "Ubuntu source code". It's not a single package, it's a **software distribution**. You'd need to compile everything, to the kernel, core utilities and libraries to Python, APT and Unity and it would take ridiculous amounts of time.

If you want to make an Ubuntu-based distro, you'll have some basic steps:

- Download Ubuntu ISO;
- Extract the ISO's content somewhere;
- Unsquashfs casper/filesystem.squashfs file inside extracted ISO;
- Correctly mount --bind /dev, /dev/pts, /proc and /sys to the unsquashfs'd filesystem and chroot into it;
- Make your changes in the chroot environment and unmount the binded filesystems;
- Create a new filesystem.squashfs from the chroot directory and place it in /casper;
- Make an ISO image with your new customized Ubuntu distro.

A more detailed approach can be found at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization .

Comment: So exactly where can I get everything, and how can I make the installer?

Comment: As I said, you can get everything in the Ubuntu ISO. And what do you mean by "make the installer"?

Comment: Yes PS I know this is against but pls upvote

Comment: Yes what? Upvote what? What do you want/need? Your questions are a bit messy, OK?

Comment: Upvote question

Comment: I want to make the installer

Comment: What installer? Sorry but you'll **have** to be more specific.

Comment: The operating systems installer ex here

Comment: https://assets.ubuntu.com/sites/ubuntu/latest/u/img/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop/image-installdesktoplongtermsupport-4.jpg

Comment: You mean Ubiquity. You don't need to "make" it or anything. Everything that you install in your custom chroot enviroment via APT or dpkg will be included in the final installation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34424/discussion-between-thomas-wilbur-and-eduardo-cola).